# Java: why is this function never called?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, compilation

```
package main;

class F {
    void f() {
        System.out.print("F.f() ");
        this.g();
    }

    void g() {
        System.out.print("F.g() ");
    }
}

class Fbis extends F {
    void f() {
        System.out.print("Fbis.f() ");
        this.g();
    }

    void g() {
        System.out.print("Fbis.g() ");
        super.f();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        F f = new Fbis();
        ((F) f).f();
    }
}
```

Hi, I'm trying to understand why the g() function in the F class is never called.
This code compiles and runs but leads to an infinite loop that show this:

```
Fbis.f() Fbis.g() F.f() Fbis.g() F.f() Fbis.g() F.f() Fbis.g() F.f() Fbis.g() F.f() Fbis.g() F.f() Fbis.g() F.f() Fbis.g() F.f() ...
```

So what happens, is that `Fbis.f` is called, which calls `Fbis.g`, which calls `F.f` but instead of calling `F.g`, `F.f` calls `Fbis.g`.

Comment: @FranzEbner that only works if he is using Eclipse ;-)

Comment: @André Playbutton vs. Shell... Playbutton wins :D

Comment: @FranzEbner Of course. Eclipse is awesome and I'm using it myself. Just saying :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, that is how inheritance works.  The `Fbis` class overrides the `g()` method so for any instance of `Fbis` calling `g()` will run the code from the `Fbis` class, even if this called from within the `F` class itself.

This is usually desirable behaviour.  For example, imagine a `delete()` method.  In a parent class this does some clean up when the object is deleted by your application.  In the child class it does extra clean-up specific for this child.  You would want the extra clean up to be done whenever `delete()` was called, even if this was from within the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

> F.f but instead of calling F.g, F.f calls Fbis.g.

Your code says

```
void f(){System.out.print("F.f() ");this.g();}
```

This means `F.f()` should call `g();` of the class which this class implements.

if you wanted Fbis.g to call F.g you would write

```
void g(){System.out.print("Fbis.g() "); super.g();}
```

Comment: I think he's thinking about `F.f()` that calls `this.g()` which ends up being `Fbis.g()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you override a method, the overridden version is always used, no matter from where you call it.

When you do `this.g()` in the base class, and the current object belongs to a sub-class, you call `g()` in the sub-class.

When you have any methods in the base class which are called from the base class, and you don't want to allow them to be replaced by a derived class, you should make that method private and final.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Fbis` class overrides the method `g()`. If you create a new object of `Fbis` the only method named `g` is the one defined in `Fbis`. Even if you call it from an inherited method it is still the only one. Otherwise said if you create an `Fbis` object `this` points to that object, also if it is used in a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

#### Method F.g() doesnt exists in Fbis anymore!

Becaus you are "Overriding" the method g() in Fbis. Understand that only using "super.g" will preserve the overriding.

Answer (score 0):

```
class F {
    void f() {
        System.out.print("F.f() ");
        this.g(); //<----- This line calls Fbis.g() not F.g() 
                  // because this is the instance of Fbis
    }
```